# Compiling single file Vue.JS components using Node.JS

Tags: vue.js, compilation, vue-component

So this is a weird one, but I have created a code editor for the web as part of a prototype for a platform I am working on, the problem is the whole idea for the code editor is that it will revolve around creating single file components and compiling them into .js files that I can include into my Vue instances using scripts. I have seen there are a few libraries out there, but I am confused.

Essentially I have created a Node.JS library that interacts with the Vue application over websocket, and what I wanted to do was pass it the file (.vue) and it will take that, compile it and return me an asset link, that I can use to render it into a preview section.

I know that I can use something like webpack, but I want a bit more control on actually compiling the library, and essentially for the front-end user I can tell them each step that is happening, and allow me to abstract the whole compilation process, so I can use any available APIs to call it and step through it, so example:

1. Receive data and parse it and convert it - might need to convert it from pug to html (example)
2. Resolve the JS, this may be typescript, or JS with ES6 features, so I need to transpile it
3. Then resolve the styling, is it using less, scss, or sass, so I need to convert that
4. Then I can put it all together, and compile the whole component together returning me a .js file

I mean I know it's a bit of a stretch... but are there a series of libraries out there that support this? and allow me to step through the compilation process but also be able to control it a little more and call it from a thread from within the Node application.

Any ideas, hints, or links to the right places would be very useful, I have spent some time looking at it, but I am hoping that someone else has already had this same issue and how they resolved it.